Linear logic: Coherence space semantics for non-atomic formulas
In Jean-Yves Girard's "Between logic and quantic: a tract" (2004) the coherence space semantics of linear logic is explained. First, Girard introduces the notion of a carrier set $\mathbb{X}$ and a coherence space $X \subset 2^{\mathbb{X}}$ as a set of subsets of the carrier set with certain properties that makes the polar of a set ${\sim} X$ model negation. Each formula of linear logic can then be assigned a coherence space, if I understand correctly. In Sec. 2.3.1, p. 9, Girard explains the coherence space semantics of additive disjunction (plus, ⨁) and additive conjunction (with, &). This explanation, however, comes with the precondition that the carrier sets $\mathbb{X}$ and $\mathbb{Y}$ are disjoint. If the carrier sets are disjoint,
$X \oplus Y = X \cup Y$
$X \& Y = \{a \cup b | a \in X, b \in Y\}$
If the carrier spaces are not disjoint, Girard advices to "do the obvious thing !" (p. 9). My question is: what should one do for overlapping carriers?
The reason this is a stumbling block for me is that for complex, non-atomic formulas, I would intuitively expect the overlap in carrier sets to have semantic significance. For example, if $A$, $B$, $C$ are all atomic formulas with associated mutually disjoint carrier sets, then $X = A \oplus B$ and $Y = B \oplus C$ would have overlapping carrier sets and this overlap reflects the shared disjunct $B$.
Checking Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_space), the "obvious thing" might be to take the disjoint union of carrier sets, i.e. to label elements of $\mathbb{X}$ and $\mathbb{Y}$ by their origin. However, intuitively this seems to misrepresent information about the common disjunct $B$ in examples like the above $X = A \oplus B$ and $Y = B \oplus C$. I've also tried to look at other sources than Girard, but they tend to use a much more category theoretical language that I find much harder to follow.

Yes, the obvious thing is to take the disjoint union. In other words, if $X$ and $Y$ have non-empty intersection, then you replace them with isomorphic coherent spaces $X' \cong X$ and $Y' \cong Y$ whose carriers are disjoint and proceed to take the union. One way to achieve this is to take $|X'| = |X| \times {1}$ and $|Y'| = |Y| \times {2}$.

@NaïmFavier, won't the disjoint union give me inequivalent semantics of the formulas $(A\oplus B) \oplus (B \oplus C)$ and $(A\oplus C)\oplus B$, despite these being equivalent in linear logic? Or even simpler, won't the disjoint union give inequivalent semantics of the equivalent formulas $A\oplus A$ and $A$?

Right; this means that $A$ and $A \oplus A$ are logically or propositionally equivalent in the sense that there are implications/morphisms back and forth, but not what the nLab calls Lambek-equivalent, which would mean that the semantics of $A$ and $A \oplus A$ are always isomorphic. Intuitively, $A \oplus A$ has one more "bit" of information than $A$, which is not captured by linear logic.

@NaïmFavier thanks for the help understanding this. It's clear now that a) disjoint union is indeed what Girard intended, and b) I need to adjust my expectations how the semantics work.
